# Wordpress custom taxonomy page

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, rewrite-rules

I've got a question that I've seen being asked before, but none of the answers solved my problems. It's something I've run into before, but never managed to solve.

I've got a clean Wordpress installation and in the `functions.php` file I've created a custom post type

```
register_nav_menu('main', 'Main navigation menu');

function add_custom_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x('Books', 'post type general name'),
        'singular_name' => _x('Book', 'post type singular name'),
        'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'book'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Add New Book'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit Book'),
        'new_item' => __('New Book'),
        'all_items' => __('All Books'),
        'view_item' => __('View Book'),
        'search_items' => __('Search Books'),
        'not_found' =>  __('No books found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('No books found in Trash'), 
        'parent_item_colon' => '',
        'menu_name' => __('Books')
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'public' => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui' => true, 
        'show_in_menu' => true, 
        'query_var' => true,
        'rewrite' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'has_archive' => true, 
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => null,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' )
    ); 

    register_post_type('book', $args);
}
```

I've made an `archive-book.php` and `single-book.php` template files for those and everything works okay. I can view the books when I go to "http://localhost/wordpress/book"
Now I want to create a custom taxonomy, so I did this in `functions.php` as well:

```
add_action('init', 'add_custom_post_type');

function add_custom_taxonomy() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'rating',
        'book',
        array(
            'label' => 'Rating',
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'query_var' => 'book',
            'has_archive' => true,
            'rewrite' => array(
                'slug' => 'book/rating'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

And the taxonomy shows up in the admin page, I can add new terms, and add them to books. But now comes the problem. I've I want to go to an overview of all books with, let's say, rating "nice", I would go to "http://localhost/wordpress/book/rating/nice". I've created the following template files: taxonomy-rating-nice.php, taxonomy-rating.php and taxonomy.php.

But somehow wordpress just shows the index.php file and doesn't list any books.
I've tried flushing the rewrite rules with:

```
add_action('init', 'custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite');
function custom_taxonomy_flush_rewrite() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

And:

```
flush_rewrite_rules(false);
```

But nothings seems to help.

So, anybody who can help me? If you need more information, please tell, cause I really want to fix this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues -

1. You're setting `query_var` to `'book'` in your custom taxonomy, which is clashing with the query var for your custom post type. change that to `true` and it will default to the name of the taxonomy, `'rating'`.
2. There is no `has_archive` argument for `register_taxonomy`, though this is probably not effecting anything. This makes sense if you think about it, since a taxonomy term is always a form of archive.
3. The last issue you may encounter is one of precedence - if multiple rewrite rules apply to a given URL, the one with highest precedence will be chosen. If you register your post type first, then your taxonomy, using your example `http://localhost/wordpress/book/rating/nice`, WordPress will think you want to load an attachment named `nice` belonging to a book named `rating`. If you register your taxonomy *first*, then register your post type, your taxonomy will take precedence in this case and everything should work as expected.